# Kubuntu can not login

Tags: kubuntu, login

when I try to login to Kubuntu through the desktop mode, a warning that says "can not enter home directory" is shown, and it throws me back to the login page.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt+F1 at the login screen and login that way, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I read about a guy with the same error message and it was due to changing the the path to the home directory before migrating the contents to the new location.

[Similar issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970388)

Maybe you inadvertently did something similar. He solution in that case was

> I started in failsafe mode and typed: "usermod -d /my/new/home [username]" but it told me, [username] is already logged in...
>   So, I created a passwd for the root user and logged in as root. Then I typed "startx". I went to system settings (where all begun) account management and I typed the old path to /home to [username]! Now I can log in again as [username]!

Maybe that will help